# Problems Retrieving String From NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

Hey guys, so I have this code:

```
SJLog(@"dict: %@",dict);
```

That prints this dictionary:

```
2011-05-04 02:37:51.537 Parking[14458:207] dict: {
    "A_SPACES" = 0;
    "DP_SPACES" = 7;
    "LOT_DESC" = "West of the Maddy Lab off of West Health Science Dr.";
    "LOT_ID" = 44;
    "LOT_NAME" = LOT57;
    "L_SPACES" = 0;
    "MC_SPACES" = 8;
    "VISITOR_SPACES" = 263;
    "permits_accepted" =     {
        A = 1;
        C = 1;
        L = 0;
    };
}
```

And I am trying to retrieve the value for LOT_DESC via the following code:

```
SJLog(@"lot description from dict: %@ ",[dict objectForKey:@"@LOT_DESC"]);
```

But I get this:

```
2011-05-04 02:37:51.537 Parking[14458:207] lot description from dict: (null)
```

And if I use `[dict valueForKey:@"@LOT_DESC"]` I get the following error:

```
2011-05-04 02:44:28.148 Parking[14505:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFDictionary 0x58c8660> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key LOT_DESC.'
```

Accessing the dictionary via `valueForKey` for all numeric values works fine. So, I have no idea what is going wrong and would really love some advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SJLog(@"lot description from dict: %@ ",[dict objectForKey:@"LOT_DESC"]);
```

Comment: Major facepalm... I feel like a f***ing dumbass right now. Thanks.